# Outlook 2016 (Desktop) Requirement Set 1.1 Add-In disabled for users

Tags: office365, manifest, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2016

We have created Outlook Add-in (SSO outlook add-in) using ASP.NET and Office JS. Few users are on Office 365 subscription version and some are on Outlook 2016 desktop version.

All users who are on Outlook Office 365 version facing no issues in seeing add-in. Whereas all users on Outlook 2016 version are seeing Add-in but it is disabled mode.

All documentation is showing the add-ins are supported for Outlook 2016. Can someone please point me or help me to understand the issue why it is disabled.

**Setup**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins

I have done enough research and provided the links I have followed to setup the add-in. If you need more information please let me know!

thanks

-Praveen.

Comment: By disabled do you mean the button is grayed out? This often means that the message that is selected is not supported by add-ins. Is it also grayed out if you open the message in a pop out window? Are the machines with grayed out versions on different build numbers? (if so what build numbers). Are you on a compose or read mail add-in? A full screenshot of the issue might also help identify any issues that may affect this but aren't obvious just by description.

Comment: We have updated users to latest version of outlook 2016 and most of the users are able to see the add-in. Only users are not seeing when we mention 1.5 requirement set, as per below comments, windows + outlook 2016 only supports 1.4. Whereas MAC supports 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Web add-ins are supported, but not SSO.

The version of MS Office does not support SSO. The required version is Office 365 (the subscription version of Office), in any monthly channel for using SSO.

If the [getAccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#sso-api-reference) API is not supported by the add-in or the Office version your add-in should respond to this error by falling back to an alternate system of user authentication. For more information, see [Requirements and Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#requirements-and-best-practices).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, the question is why add-in is disabled. If the office doesn't support SSO then the implementation we have done will take care of the dialog box and generate token and it will work. We have that implementation already. The actual question asked was why it is disabled for users. I have exact same version of outlook 2016 (16.0.4939.1001) on couple of dev machines and we are able to see the add-in working fine. Any other settings at tenant level or such I need to know? Thanks

Comment: What requirement set do you have specified in the manifest ? Office2016 on windows supports only up to 1.4. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets

Comment: Looks like this is one of the issue I had. Some machines we have tested are with 1.5 requirement set in manifest. Those machines I see it is disabled because they are all Outlook 2016. I think 1.4 is the version it supports in Windows for 2016 version. Whereas MaC all good.